# Prove that $\delta^*(q,wv)=\delta^*(\delta^*(q,w),v)$

Tags: automata, regular-language, finite-automata

Imagine we have a language like $L$ with alphabet $\Sigma$ and the set of words of $L$ called $\Sigma^*$ ( notice that a word can have zero characters).
We define $\delta^*$ recursively like this :

For each $a \in \Sigma$, $w \in \Sigma^*$ and $q \in Q$ :

$(1)$ $\delta^*(q,\lambda)=q$
$(2)$ $\delta^*(q,wa)=\delta(\delta^*(q,w),a)$

Now prove that for each two strings like $w$ and $v$, $\delta^*(q,wv)=\delta^*(\delta^*(q,w),v)$.

Note : what i tried was induction on $|v|$ but it didn't work.
For $|v|=0$ we have this: $\delta^*(q,wv)=\delta^*(q,w\lambda)=\delta^*(q,w)=\delta^*(\delta^*(q,w),\lambda)=\delta^*(\delta^*(q,w),v)$.

Assume that for $|v|=n-1$ its true that : $\delta^*(q,wv)=\delta^*(\delta^*(q,w),v)$.

Now i'm stuck on this : How to show that its true for $|v|=n$ ?

Comment: It should have. would you mind showing us what you tried so we can spot the mistake? induction on $|v|$ should works without problem.

Comment: @wece for $|v|=0$ its obvious. i assumed that for $|v|=n-1$ its true and i don't know how to reach $|v|=n$. maybe it's just a mistake but i'm confused with many $\delta$'s & $\delta^*$'s

Comment: Ok. Assume it's true for $|v|=n-1$. Take $v$ with $|v|=n$, $v=v'a$ with $|v'|=n-1$, then apply (2) on $wv'a$, use the induction hypothesis on $wv'$ (here you have lot of $\delta$ and $\delta^*$ but dont be afraid) you can now use (2) (in the other direction to obtain the desired form.

Comment: Did it help or are you still stuck?

Comment: @wece thank you dude :) it worked ... i don't know what to do with my question now ... should i delete it ?

Comment: Nah, keep it (imho).

Comment: I'll provide an answer so that the question is marked answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By induction on $|v|$.

If $v=\lambda$, then $\delta^*(q,wv)=\delta^*(q,w)=\delta^*(\delta^*(q,w),\lambda)=\delta^*(\delta^*(q,w),v)$.

Assume that for all $v$ such that $|v|=n-1$ the property is true.

Let $v$ be such that $|v|=n$, assume (without loss of generality) that $v=v'a$. Then:
using (1)
$$\delta^*(q,wv)=\delta^*(q,wv'a)=\delta(\delta^*(q,wv'),a)$$
using the induction hypothesis we know that:
$$\delta^*(q,wv')=\delta^*(\delta^*(q,w),v')$$
thus
$$ \delta^*(q,wv)=\delta(\delta^*(\delta^*(q,w),v'),a)$$
by applying (2) we obtain:
$$ \delta^*(q,wv)=\delta^*(\delta^*(q,w),v'a)$$
thus
$$\delta^*(q,wv)=\delta^*(\delta^*(q,w),v)$$